# How do I add an existing role to a user in my server?

Tags: python, discord

Code:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def mute(ctx, *, member: discord.Member):
  role = discord.utils.get(bot.roles, name="Muted")
  await bot.add_roles(member, role)
```

I've been trying for hours there are 0 useful YouTube videos at all.
I've been at this for hours anything would be helpful at this point.

Comment: Have you verified that the command is running and that it's receiving the proper arguments?

Comment: I am sorta new to discord.py can explain what you mean?  If you mean when I execute the command in the server if the args are matching to those required then the answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def mute(ctx, *, member: discord.Member):
  role = discord.utils.get(bot.roles, name="Muted")
  await member.add_roles(member, role)
```

Try changing `bot.add_roles` to `member.add_roles`.